# Printing the expected mean of rolls after all 6 sides are shown

Tags: python

I have an issue trying to print the count of the number of rolls it takes to roll all 6 sides

But for some reason every time I print count it always shows as 0.

So until all six sides are rolled it will keep incrementing the count. Once it found all six sides to make the while loop end and print the count.

```
import random
count = 0
while True:
    outcomes = set()

# remember how many rolls we have made
    rolls = 0

# keep going until we roll all six sides
    while len(outcomes) != 6:
        rolls += 1
        outcomes.add(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
        if(len(outcomes) == 6):
           stop = True
           break
    if stop:
        break
    else:
        count+=1
print(f'Count is {count}')
```

Comment: Because all of the work is being done in your iner `while` loop, your `else` never triggers, and never increments the counter. How about printing `rolls` instead?

Comment: You need to use `rolls`, I suppose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not increasing the value of `count`. In addition, your code is a bit messy. You can use just one while loop instead of two nested as follows:

```
import random
count = 0
outcomes = set()

while True:
    outcomes.add(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]))

    if len(outcomes) == 6:
        break
    count += 1

print(f'Count is {count}')
```

Notice that `count += 1` is equivalent to `count = count + 1`.

Comment: I keep getting an invalid identifier? I see what your code is doing but I'm not sure what that error means .

Comment: @l.m., sorry for a strange reason some characters were added that I didn't realize. Can you try now, it should be working.

Comment: Got it to work now I see what you did now by using count, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`count` is 0 because you never change it.

The inner loop keeps adding to `outcomes` until it has a length of 6, at which point `stop`  is set to true, breaking the inner loop *and* the outer loop *before* `count` is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code never increments count variable. This can be simply done like this;

```
import random

count = 0
outcomes = set()

while len(outcomes) != 6:
    outcomes.add(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
    count += 1

print(f'Count is {count}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you are never executing count+=1. The code loops through the second while until len(outcomes) == 6.

When that happens, you are setting 'stop' to 'True', and breaking the inner while, immediately after, you are evaluating 'stop' (which is 'True'), and breaking the outer while.

Here is an alternative approach:

```py
import random
outcomes = set()
rolls = 0
while (len(outcomes) != 6):
    outcomes.add(random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
    rolls += 1
print('The dice was rolled {} times.'.format(rolls)
```